# Como configurar tamanho da saída na opção "script" do SqlDeveloper

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

Oracle - SqlDeveloper -  Versão 4.1.3.20 Build MAIN-20.78

Ao executar um bloco SQL temo duas opções (Executar Instrução ou Executar Script), nesta opção , após uma atualização feita , ocorre uma limitação no tamanho da saída , em que ponto do SqlDeveloper posso configurar esta saída ?

Ocorre uma quebra de linha e preciso de uma linha única.

---

Exemplo

```
select *
from dba_tables 
where rownum < 2

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
SYS                            ICOL$                          

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
SYSTEM                         C_OBJ#                         

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
                               VALID             0          0          0 

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
         0                                  139264 

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
                                 204800                                       1

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
                             2147483645                                        

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
         1                                       1 YES N     276957      10170 

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
                                      0          0          0 

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
                                     32                                       0

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
                                      0 1          1          N     ENABLED  

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
                                 276957 01/07/15      NO               N N NO  

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
DEFAULT DEFAULT DEFAULT DISABLED YES NO                  DISABLED YES 

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
SYS                            DISABLED DISABLED              NO  NO  YES 

OWNER                          TABLE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS
------------------------------ -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 MAX_TRANS                          INITIAL_EXTENT
---------- ---------------------------------------
                            NEXT_EXTENT                             MIN_EXTENTS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                            MAX_EXTENTS                            PCT_INCREASE
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
 FREELISTS                         FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS     BLOCKS
---------- --------------------------------------- --- - ---------- ----------
                           EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT
--------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
                            AVG_ROW_LEN               AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
                    NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE     INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----- --------
                            SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES
--------------------------------------- ------------- --- ------------ - - ---
BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON
------- ------- ------- -------- --- --- --------------- -------- ---
CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_
------------------------------ -------- -------- ------------ --- --- --- -------
DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver assim :

Crio o seguinte script em arquivo .sql (texto)

```
set linesize 10000
set pagesize 10000
```

Indo em Ferramentas / Preferencias / Banco de Dados
aponto este arquivo

Não sei se é a melhor das soluções , pois o nome das colunas fica truncado.

e aponto o caminho